# PHP for loop with AJAX div auto refresh

Tags: php, ajax

the problem with my code is that when I print the php ajax div inside the for loop, I get one single index of the loop when the loop has 2 index.

example of my code:

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DeportesRulz.com</title>
<link charset="utf-8" href="./css/tablaodds.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
            function AJAX(){
            try{
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            return xmlHttp;
            }
            catch (e){
            try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); // Internet Explorer
            return xmlHttp;
            }
            catch (e){
            try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            return xmlHttp;
            }
            catch (e){
            alert('Your browser does not support AJAX.');
            return false;
            }
            }
            }
            }


            // Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request (common function)

            function fetch_unix_timestamp()
            {
                return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
            }
<?php
//Obtener fecha
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
$fechaabrev = strftime("Sat, %b 17, %y");
//[Variables globales]
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./MLB.xml');
$juegos = count($xml->EventType->Date);
//Obtener todos los juegos
for ($i=0;$i<=$juegos-1;$i++) {
    //Obtener solo juegos del dia
    if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->attributes()->DTEXT == $fechaabrev){
        $juegosdeldia = count($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event);
        //Bucle principal juegos del dia
        for ($k=0;$k<=$juegosdeldia-1;$k++) {
            $juego_dia = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->attributes()->DTEXT.' ';
            $juego_horaf = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Time->attributes()->TTEXT.' ';
            $juego_horaf = explode(" ", $juego_horaf);
            $juego_hora = $juego_horaf[0];
            $juego_live = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->attributes()->LIVE_ENABLED.' ';
            $juego_ligaf = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->NOTE.' ';
            $juego_ligaf = explode(" ", $juego_ligaf);
            if ($juego_ligaf[0] == 'AMERICAN'){
                $juego_liga = 'American League';
            } else if ($juego_ligaf[0] == 'NATIONAL'){
                $juego_liga = 'National League';
            }

            $equipos = count($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor);
            //Bucle equipos
            for ($j=0;$j<=$equipos-1;$j++) {
                //Obtener equipo A
                if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NUM == 2){
                    $equipo_a = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NAME;
                }//--Fin Obtener equipo A--
                //Obtener equipo B
                if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NUM == 1){
                    $equipo_b = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NAME;
                }//--Fin Obtener equipo B--
            }//--Fin Bucle equipos--

//--------------------------------------------[Imprimiendo datos]---------------------------------------------------------//

            $headscript = "

            function refreshdiv_otherdiv(){

            // Customise those settings

            var seconds = 5;
            var divid = 'live[$k]';
            var url = './file1.php?row=[$k]';

            var xmlHttp_three = AJAX();

            // No cache

            var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
            var nocacheurl = url+'?t='+timestamp;


            // The code...

            xmlHttp_three.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlHttp_three.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp_three.responseText;
            setTimeout('refreshdiv_otherdiv()',seconds*1000);
            }
            }
            xmlHttp_three.open('GET',nocacheurl,true);
            xmlHttp_three.send(null);
            }

            // Start the refreshing process

            var seconds;
            window.onload = function startrefresh(){
            setTimeout('refreshdiv_otherdiv()',seconds*1000);
            }
            ";
            if ($juegosdeldia == 1){
                echo "$headscript</script></head><body><script type='text/javascript'>refreshdiv_live[$k]();</script><table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class='tablehead' style='background-color:white;'><tbody><tr class='stathead'><td colspan='5' style='background-color:#0B3861;color:white;'>$equipo_a vs $equipo_b | [MLB] $juego_liga <div name='live[$k]' id='live[$k]'></div></tr><tr class='colhead' style='text-align:center;'><td>$juego_hora</td><td>A GANAR</td><td>ALTA/BAJA (6.5)</td><td>RUN LINE</td><td>ALTA/BAJA (3.5 | 5to inning)</td></tr><div id='odds'></div></tbody></table></body></html>";
            } else if ($juegosdeldia > 1){
                if ($k == 0){
                    echo "$headscript";
                } else if ($k > 0){
                    echo "$headscript</script></head><body><script type='text/javascript'>refreshdiv_live[$k]();</script><table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class='tablehead' style='background-color:white;'><tbody><tr class='stathead'><td colspan='5' style='background-color:#0B3861;color:white;'>$equipo_a vs $equipo_b | [MLB] $juego_liga <div name='live[$k]' id='live[$k]'></div></tr><tr class='colhead' style='text-align:center;'><td>$juego_hora</td><td>A GANAR</td><td>ALTA/BAJA (6.5)</td><td>RUN LINE</td><td>ALTA/BAJA (3.5 | 5to inning)</td></tr><div id='odds'></div></tbody></table></body></html>";
                }
            }
            echo "";


//------------------------------------------[Fin Imprimiendo datos]---------------------------------------------------------//

        }//--Fin Bucle principal juegos del dia--
    }//--Fin Obtener solo juegos del dia--
}//--Fin Obtener todos los juegos--

?>
```

MLB.xml

```
<Schedule PUBLISH_DATE="10/18/2015" PUBLISH_TIME="08:02" TS="1445212923955"><EventType GROUP="E" ID="MLB" NAME="Baseball - MLB" SPORT="B"><Date DTEXT="Fri, Oct 16, 15" TS="1444968000000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="687326" LIVE_ENABLED="true" LineOrder="D" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays @ Kansas City Royals" PXP_GAME_ID="8228712" Publish="true" STATUS="Final"><Competitor ID="687326-1633" NAME="Kansas City Royals" NUM="1" ROT="952"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="65735691" NUMBER="" VALUE="+116"><Odds FRACTION="23/20" Line="+116" MULTIPLIER="2.16" RISK="100" WIN="116"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="65726357" NUMBER="1½" VALUE="+1½ (-140)"><Odds FRACTION="8/11" Line="-140" MULTIPLIER="1.714" RISK="140" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><Competitor ID="687326-9999" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays" NUM="2" ROT="951"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="65735690" NUMBER="" VALUE="-126"><Odds FRACTION="3/4" Line="-126" MULTIPLIER="1.794" RISK="126" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="65726356" NUMBER="-1½" VALUE="-1½ (+120)"><Odds FRACTION="6/5" Line="+120" MULTIPLIER="2.20" RISK="100" WIN="120"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><NOTE>AMERICAN LEAGUE - CHAMPIONSHIP SERIES - GAME #1</NOTE><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445040420000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"><Choice ID="65734371" NUMBER="8.0" VALUE="+8.0 (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Over</Choice><Choice ID="65734372" NUMBER="8.0" VALUE="+8.0 (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Under</Choice></Line></Event></Date><Date DTEXT="Sat, Oct 17, 15" TS="1445054400000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="687327" LIVE_ENABLED="true" LineOrder="D" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays @ Kansas City Royals" PXP_GAME_ID="8228714" Publish="true" STATUS="Final"><Competitor ID="687327-1633" NAME="Kansas City Royals" NUM="1" ROT="956"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66123598" NUMBER="" VALUE="+139"><Odds FRACTION="11/8" Line="+139" MULTIPLIER="2.39" RISK="100" WIN="139"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66118320" NUMBER="1½" VALUE="+1½ (-115)"><Odds FRACTION="17/20" Line="-115" MULTIPLIER="1.87" RISK="115" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><Competitor ID="687327-9999" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays" NUM="2" ROT="955"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66123597" NUMBER="" VALUE="-154"><Odds FRACTION="8/13" Line="-154" MULTIPLIER="1.649" RISK="154" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66118319" NUMBER="-1½" VALUE="-1½ (-105)"><Odds FRACTION="20/21" Line="-105" MULTIPLIER="1.952" RISK="105" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><NOTE>AMERICAN LEAGUE CHAMPIONSHIP SERIES GAME #2</NOTE><Time TTEXT="04:07PM EDT" TS="1445112420000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"><Choice ID="66104749" NUMBER="7½" VALUE="+7½ (+115)"><Odds FRACTION="23/20" Line="+115" MULTIPLIER="2.15" RISK="100" WIN="115"/>Over</Choice><Choice ID="66104750" NUMBER="7½" VALUE="+7½ (-135)"><Odds FRACTION="8/11" Line="-135" MULTIPLIER="1.741" RISK="135" WIN="100"/>Under</Choice></Line></Event><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="688238" LIVE_ENABLED="true" LineOrder="D" NAME="Chicago Cubs @ New York Mets" PXP_GAME_ID="8232308" Publish="true" STATUS="Closed"><Competitor ID="688238-10457" NAME="New York Mets" NUM="1" ROT="954"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66200407" NUMBER="" VALUE="-110"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66167912" NUMBER="-1½" VALUE="-1½ (+190)"><Odds FRACTION="19/10" Line="+190" MULTIPLIER="2.90" RISK="100" WIN="190"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><Competitor ID="688238-10395" NAME="Chicago Cubs" NUM="2" ROT="953"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66200406" NUMBER="" VALUE="EVEN"><Odds FRACTION="1/1" Line="EVEN" MULTIPLIER="2.00" RISK="100" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66167911" NUMBER="1½" VALUE="+1½ (-230)"><Odds FRACTION="2/5" Line="-230" MULTIPLIER="1.435" RISK="230" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><NOTE>NATIONAL LEAGUE CHAMPIONSHIP SERIES GAME #1</NOTE><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445126820000"/><WagerStopTime TTEXT="11:44PM EDT" TS="1445139857447"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"><Choice ID="66201325" NUMBER="6.0" VALUE="+6.0 (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Over</Choice><Choice ID="66201326" NUMBER="6.0" VALUE="+6.0 (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Under</Choice></Line></Event></Date><Date DTEXT="Sun, Oct 18, 15" TS="1445140800000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="688239" LIVE_ENABLED="true" LineOrder="D" NAME="Chicago Cubs @ New York Mets" PXP_GAME_ID="8232310" Publish="true" STATUS="Open"><Competitor ID="688239-10457" NAME="New York Mets" NUM="1" ROT="958"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66645325" NUMBER="" VALUE="+138"><Odds FRACTION="11/8" Line="+138" MULTIPLIER="2.38" RISK="100" WIN="138"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66611035" NUMBER="1½" VALUE="+1½ (-135)"><Odds FRACTION="8/11" Line="-135" MULTIPLIER="1.741" RISK="135" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><Competitor ID="688239-10395" NAME="Chicago Cubs" NUM="2" ROT="957"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66645324" NUMBER="" VALUE="-153"><Odds FRACTION="4/6" Line="-153" MULTIPLIER="1.654" RISK="153" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66611034" NUMBER="-1½" VALUE="-1½ (+115)"><Odds FRACTION="23/20" Line="+115" MULTIPLIER="2.15" RISK="100" WIN="115"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><NOTE>NATIONAL LEAGUE CHAMPIONSHIP SERIES New York Mets leads 1-0</NOTE><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445213220000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"><Choice ID="66630752" NUMBER="5½" VALUE="+5½ (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Over</Choice><Choice ID="66630753" NUMBER="5½" VALUE="+5½ (-110)"><Odds FRACTION="10/11" Line="-110" MULTIPLIER="1.909" RISK="110" WIN="100"/>Under</Choice></Line></Event></Date><Date DTEXT="Mon, Oct 19, 15" TS="1445227200000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="687328" LIVE_ENABLED="false" LineOrder="D" NAME="Kansas City Royals @ Toronto Blue Jays" PXP_GAME_ID="8228716" Publish="true" STATUS="Open"><Competitor ID="687328-9999" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays" NUM="1" ROT="960"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66645502" NUMBER="" VALUE="-170"><Odds FRACTION="4/7" Line="-170" MULTIPLIER="1.588" RISK="170" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66604018" NUMBER="-1½" VALUE="-1½ (+115)"><Odds FRACTION="23/20" Line="+115" MULTIPLIER="2.15" RISK="100" WIN="115"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><Competitor ID="687328-1633" NAME="Kansas City Royals" NUM="2" ROT="959"><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"><Choice ID="66645501" NUMBER="" VALUE="+150"><Odds FRACTION="6/4" Line="+150" MULTIPLIER="2.50" RISK="100" WIN="150"/></Choice></Line><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"><Choice ID="66604019" NUMBER="1½" VALUE="+1½ (-145)"><Odds FRACTION="4/6" Line="-145" MULTIPLIER="1.69" RISK="145" WIN="100"/></Choice></Line></Competitor><NOTE>AMERICAN LEAGUE CHAMPIONSHIP SERIES -  Kansas City lead series 2-0</NOTE><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445299620000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"><Choice ID="66604027" NUMBER="8.0" VALUE="+8.0 (-115)"><Odds FRACTION="17/20" Line="-115" MULTIPLIER="1.87" RISK="115" WIN="100"/>Over</Choice><Choice ID="66604026" NUMBER="8.0" VALUE="+8.0 (-115)"><Odds FRACTION="17/20" Line="-115" MULTIPLIER="1.87" RISK="115" WIN="100"/>Under</Choice></Line></Event></Date><Date DTEXT="Tue, Oct 20, 15" TS="1445313600000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="687329" LIVE_ENABLED="false" LineOrder="D" NAME="Kansas City Royals @ Toronto Blue Jays" PXP_GAME_ID="8228718" Publish="true" STATUS="Open"><Competitor ID="687329-9999" NAME="Toronto Blue Jays" NUM="1" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Competitor ID="687329-1633" NAME="Kansas City Royals" NUM="2" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Time TTEXT="04:07PM EDT" TS="1445371620000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"/></Event><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="688237" LIVE_ENABLED="false" LineOrder="D" NAME="New York Mets @ Chicago Cubs" PXP_GAME_ID="8232312" Publish="true" STATUS="Open"><Competitor ID="688237-10395" NAME="Chicago Cubs" NUM="1" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Competitor ID="688237-10457" NAME="New York Mets" NUM="2" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445386020000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"/></Event></Date><Date DTEXT="Wed, Oct 21, 15" TS="1445400000000"><Event DenySameGame="false" GAME_STATUS="" ID="688236" LIVE_ENABLED="false" LineOrder="D" NAME="New York Mets @ Chicago Cubs" PXP_GAME_ID="8232314" Publish="true" STATUS="Open"><Competitor ID="688236-10395" NAME="Chicago Cubs" NUM="1" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Competitor ID="688236-10457" NAME="New York Mets" NUM="2" ROT=""><Line ORDER="2" TYPE="Moneyline"/><Line ORDER="1" TYPE="Runline"/></Competitor><Time TTEXT="08:07PM EDT" TS="1445472420000"/><Line ORDER="3" TYPE="Total"/></Event></Date><SEGMENT CODE="MLBWG" SEQUENCE_NUMBER="1" SHORT_NAME="Game" NAME="Whole Game" EventType="MLB"/></EventType></Schedule>
```

I tried putting the code inside the loop ajax but I can not make this work.

file1.php

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["row"]);
```

sorry for my bad explication... in the ajax code change:

```
var url = "./file1.php?row=[$k]";
```

And add inside the loop.

my code is bad :/

Comment: Where is `file1.php`, and you are not using `jquery` in this code sample, though your title and tag say so.

Comment: What php ajax are you talking about? is that in file1.php? Also, where is `refreshdiv_live()` defined?

Comment: @bonesbrigade sorry for my bad english, file1.php is getting the numbers of row for loop through GET parameter.

Comment: @Terminus "function refreshdiv_otherdiv()" is defined

Comment: Immediately after your `<body>` tag, you have `
<script type='text/javascript'>refreshdiv_live();</script>` Is that function not relevant here?

Comment: I need the function to add multiple ajax div or not?

Comment: i'm sorry i can't understand what the problem is. When I run your code without the `window.onload = function startrefresh(){
    setTimeout('refreshdiv_otherdiv()',seconds*1000);
}` i get this http://jsfiddle.net/9q88e5ot/ Can you tell me what output you are expecting? I think you want row numbers on there?

Comment: @Terminus i edit my index.php code, please check it, but i keep the problem

Comment: so you want your output to look like this http://jsfiddle.net/9q88e5ot/1/ ?

Comment: @Terminus yes, check http://jsfiddle.net/9q88e5ot/3/ The Online/Offline status with auto refresh in ajax (The status content is inside of file1.php)

Comment: jtox, i see it. where do the online/offline statuses come from? can you add that to your question?

Comment: @Terminus from file1.php (the content is a parser of json file)

Comment: and it can figure out what the correct status is simply by taking the row number?

Comment: yes, with the number of row, I can get the status of the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take this advice seriously: read more about programming. Especially the basics like: variables, functions, and scope. And if you're going to keep working with javascript, learn about closures (after learning the other stuff).

I think you were trying to have the PHP code print a separate function for each "live" div. You can just make the div a parameter to the function, and then call the function for each div.

There are some notes about the code that i've put in as comments in the code. Be sure to remove them after reading them (unless you find them useful to remember :)

```
// don't forget to add a doctype. since you didn't i'm picking HTML5
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
// also add a character set
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>DeportesRulz.com</title>
<script>
    function AJAX() {
        try{
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
            return xmlHttp;
        }
        catch (e) {
            try{
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP'); // Internet Explorer
            return xmlHttp;
            }
            catch (e) {
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                    return xmlHttp;
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert('Your browser does not support AJAX.');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request (common function)
    function fetch_unix_timestamp() {
        return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
    }

    //takes a div element as a parameter. the data-rownum on that div will be used as the rownumber passed to file1.php
    function refreshLiveStatus(targetDiv) {
        // access the data-rownum attribute of the targetDiv
        var rowNum = targetDiv.dataset['rownum'];
        // if you don't need the square brackets, remove them
        var url = './file1.php?row=[' + rowNum + ']';

        var xmlHttp_three = AJAX();

        // No cache
        var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
        // you had `url+'?t='+timestamp` here before. you can't have multiple '?' in a url like that. you need to use `&` as below
        var nocacheurl = url+'&t='+timestamp;

        // The code...
        xmlHttp_three.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlHttp_three.readyState==4) {
                targetDiv.innerHTML=xmlHttp_three.responseText;
                // start the next refresh
                setTimeout(function() {
                    refreshLiveStatus(targetDiv);
                },seconds);
            }
        }
        xmlHttp_three.open('GET',nocacheurl,true);
        xmlHttp_three.send(null);
    }

    var seconds = 5; // just set it here so you don't have to keep setting the variable (unless you want different refresh rates??)
    seconds *= 1000; // if they're seconds make them seconds and save yourself the trouble of having to remember to do `* 1000` everywhere
    // Start the refreshing process
    // function to replace window.onload below. It's not necessary to replace window.onload but this will let you easily add more than one function to the window.onload
    // console logs left in for science
    function ready(fn) {
        console.log('readying');
        if (document.readyState != 'loading') {
            console.log('loading...');
            fn();
        } else {
            console.log('content not loaded');
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
        }
    }

    ready(function() {
        // querySelectorAll lets you use CSS selectors to select HTML elements. Note that the `liveStatus` class is added in the PHP code below.
        var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.liveStatus');
        console.log(divs); // left here for you to what's selected
        for(var i = 0, imax = divs.length; i < imax; i++) {
            // the below is a closure. definitely read about these if you don't know what they are already
            (function(liveDiv) {
                refreshLiveStatus(liveDiv);
            })(divs[i]);
        }
    });

    // style the .liveStatus div. leave it out and see what happens
    </script>
    <style type='text/css'>
        div.liveStatus {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Obtener fecha
date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
$fechaabrev = strftime("Sat, %b 17, %y");
//[Variables globales]
$xml = simplexml_load_file('./MLB.xml');
$juegos = count($xml->EventType->Date);
//Obtener todos los juegos
// you can use `$i<$juegos` instead of `$i<=$juegos-1` and save having to do that subtraction
for ($i=0;$i<$juegos;$i++) {
    //Obtener solo juegos del dia
    if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->attributes()->DTEXT == $fechaabrev) {
        $juegosdeldia = count($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event);
        //Bucle principal juegos del dia
        for ($k=0;$k<$juegosdeldia;$k++) {
            $juego_dia = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->attributes()->DTEXT.' ';
            $juego_horaf = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Time->attributes()->TTEXT.' ';
            $juego_horaf = explode(" ", $juego_horaf);
            $juego_hora = $juego_horaf[0];
            $juego_live = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->attributes()->LIVE_ENABLED.' ';
            $juego_ligaf = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->NOTE.' ';
            $juego_ligaf = explode(" ", $juego_ligaf);
            if ($juego_ligaf[0] == 'AMERICAN') {
                $juego_liga = 'American League';
            } else if ($juego_ligaf[0] == 'NATIONAL') {
                $juego_liga = 'National League';
            }

            $equipos = count($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor);
            //Bucle equipos
            for ($j=0;$j<=$equipos-1;$j++) {
                //Obtener equipo A
                if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NUM == 2) {
                    $equipo_a = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NAME;
                }//--Fin Obtener equipo A--
                //Obtener equipo B
                if ($xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NUM == 1) {
                    $equipo_b = $xml->EventType->Date[$i]->Event[$k]->Competitor[$j]->attributes()->NAME;
                }//--Fin Obtener equipo B--
            }//--Fin Bucle equipos--

//--------------------------------------------[Imprimiendo datos]---------------------------------------------------------//
            // note how we add the rownumber with `...[" . ($k+1) . "]...`
            // also see how we added the `liveStatus` class AND the data-rownum attribute to the "live" div
            echo "
    <table cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class='tablehead' style='background-color:white;'>
        <tbody>
            <tr class='stathead'>
                <td colspan='5' style='background-color:#0B3861;color:white;'>
                    [" . ($k+1) . "] $equipo_a vs $equipo_b | [MLB] $juego_liga
                    <div class='liveStatus' name='live[$k]' data-rownum='$k' id='live[$k]'></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colhead' style='text-align:center;'>
                <td>$juego_hora</td>
                <td>A GANAR</td>
                <td>ALTA/BAJA (6.5)</td>
                <td>RUN LINE</td>
                <td>
                    ALTA/BAJA (3.5 | 5to inning)
                    <div id='odds'></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>";


//------------------------------------------[Fin Imprimiendo datos]---------------------------------------------------------//

        }//--Fin Bucle principal juegos del dia--
    }//--Fin Obtener solo juegos del dia--
}//--Fin Obtener todos los juegos--

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhh very very thanks!! It has worked perfectly, if I could give you many points, thanks again for taking the time to explain and make the code again.